# Getting top 100 words with highest document frequency in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, word-frequency

Suppose I have a pandas series like this:

```
0  "sun moon earth moon"
1  "sun saturn mercury saturn"
2  "sun earth mars"
3  "sun earth saturn sun saturn"
```

I want to get the top 3 words with the highest row ("document") frequency **irrespective** of the frequency within a single row ("document").

For overall frequency I can just collect all the words from all rows in a string, do a split, convert back to series and use `value_counts`. In that case, the top 3 frequencies would be:

```
1. sun:    5
2. saturn: 4
3. earth:  3
```

But the document frequencies, i.e. the **number of rows in which a word occurs**, would be

```
1. sun:    4
2. earth:  3
3. saturn: 2
```

A way I can think of off the top of my head is to apply a lambda function to the series, splitting each string, making a set out of it, then combining all words into a single set, making a series out of that and then using `value_counts`. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because performance is important use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter([y for x in s for y in x.split()]).most_common(3)
print (a)
[('sun', 5), ('saturn', 4), ('earth', 3)]

b = Counter([y for x in s for y in set(x.split())]).most_common(3)
print (b)
[('sun', 4), ('earth', 3), ('saturn', 2)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['val','count'])
#df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['val','count'])
print (df1)
      val  count
0     sun      5
1  saturn      4
2   earth      3
```

Pandas alternatives:

```
a = s.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().head(3)
print (a)
sun       5
saturn    4
earth     3
dtype: int64

b = (s.str.split(expand=True)
      .stack()
      .reset_index(name='val')
      .drop_duplicates(['val', 'level_0'])['val']
      .value_counts()
      .head(3))
print (b)
sun       4
earth     3
saturn    2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```